How I can also push the commit generated in my husky pre-push hook script?
In my husky pre-push hook, I bump the version in package.json by a user's choice:
# 
# Copyright 2024 Cypriot Free Software Foundation
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, 
# to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), 
# to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, 
# sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
# subject to the following conditions:
# 
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
# INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. 
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, 
# WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, 
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#

#!/bin/bash

test -n "$BASH_VERSION" || exec /bin/bash $0 "$@"

IFS=' '

npm run generate-exports
git commit -m "Autoganarated exports" package.json 

current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $current_branch != "dev" ]; then
  echo "Ommiting version bump because current branch is ${current_branch}" 
  exit 0
fi

echo "Pushing ${current_branch}"

current_version=$(npm run version -s)

echo "Current version: $current_version"

patch_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i patch)
minor_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i minor)
major_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i major)

# Choose the version bump type
PS3="Select the version bump type: "
select bump_type in "patch - Bump into ${patch_version}" "minor - Bump into ${minor_version}" "major - Bump into ${major_version}" "none - Keep Same"; do

  case $bump_type in
    "patch"*)
      # Increment version based on the chosen bump type
      new_version="patch"
      break
      ;;
    "minor"*)
        new_version="minor"
        break
        ;;
    "major"*)
        new_version="major"
        break
        ;;
    "none"*)
      echo "No version selected, skipping bump."
      exit 0
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid selection, please choose a valid option."
      ;;
  esac
done <&2

echo "Bumping version to $new_version"

# Update package.json with the new version
new_version=$(npm version ${new_version} --no-git-tag-version --no-commit-hooks --force --silent)

echo "Version bumped to $new_version"

echo "Keep package-lock.json up to spec"
npm install
git commit -m "AutoBump Version" package.json package-lock.json

But in order to push the generated commit:
git commit -m "AutoBump Version" package.json package-lock.json

I need to manually git push a second time thus re-running the hook. How I can upon push also to push the commit created by:
git commit -m "AutoBump Version" package.json package-lock.json


Maybe avoid doing another commit/sub-push if latest commit is an "AutoBump Version". Refer to the local reference passed to the script to make it consistent. You can cancel the parent push by exiting with a non-zero. See githooks(5).

An approach of mine is just push without further verification:
# 
# Copyright 2024 Cypriot Free Software Foundation
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, 
# to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), 
# to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, 
# sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
# subject to the following conditions:
# 
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
# INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. 
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, 
# WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, 
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#

#!/bin/bash

test -n "$BASH_VERSION" || exec /bin/bash $0 "$@"

IFS=' '

npm run generate-exports
git commit -m "[Husky pre-push hook] Autoganarated exports" package.json 

current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $current_branch != "dev" ]; then
  echo "Ommiting version bump because current branch is ${current_branch}" 
  git push origin --no-verify "$current_branch"
  exit 0
fi

echo "Pushing ${current_branch}"


current_version=$(npm run version -s)

echo "Current version: $current_version"

patch_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i patch)
minor_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i minor)
major_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i major)

# Choose the version bump type
PS3="Select the version bump type: "
select bump_type in "patch - Bump into ${patch_version}" "minor - Bump into ${minor_version}" "major - Bump into ${major_version}" "none - Keep Same"; do

  case $bump_type in
    "patch"*)
      # Increment version based on the chosen bump type
      new_version="patch"
      break
      ;;
    "minor"*)
        new_version="minor"
        break
        ;;
    "major"*)
        new_version="major"
        break
        ;;
    "none"*)
      echo "No version selected, skipping bump."
      exit 0
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid selection, please choose a valid option."
      ;;
  esac
done <&2

echo "Bumping version to $new_version"

# Update package.json with the new version
new_version=$(npm version ${new_version} --no-git-tag-version --no-commit-hooks --force --silent)

echo "Version bumped to $new_version"

echo "Keep package-lock.json up to spec"
npm install
git commit -m "[Husky pre-push hook] AutoBump Version" package.json package-lock.json


# Push the new commit
echo "Pushing the new commit"
git push origin --no-verify "$current_branch"

echo "Finished pushing the new commit"

As you can see upon:
git push origin --no-verify "$current_branch"

I do push but I place --no-verify therefore pre-push hook won't be executed for a second time upon push.
In your case you may get the error:
! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/dev': is at XXXXX but expected XXX)

This is because upon push the head has been changed. Do not be alarmed
You can avoid second push alltogether either via returning a nonzero exist status code:
exit 1

Also ensure that upon den NO ONE pushes except you. Because version bumps do happen upon dev. Use seperate branches for feature development.
